# Exception on Hazelcast addItemListener

Tags: java, hazelcast

When I try add Item listener from Hazelcast java client, I get the following exception:

```
com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastException: Listener ClientRegistrationKey{ userRegistrationId='d9a09f3b-d56c-43e9-814a-a8f5c6b89ca0'} can not be added to member Member [192.168.1.105]:5702 - 2dc26b1a-dbb4-449a-a7e2-6b8ff9fe1964 
at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.listener.ClientSmartListenerService.register(ClientSmartListenerService.java:102)  
at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.listener.ClientSmartListenerService.access$000(ClientSmartListenerService.java:52) 
at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.listener.ClientSmartListenerService$1.call(ClientSmartListenerService.java:81) 
at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.listener.ClientSmartListenerService$1.call(ClientSmartListenerService.java:74) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)  
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76)
at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:92)

Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientInvocationFuture.newTimeoutException(ClientInvocationFuture.java:55)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:197)
at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.listener.ClientSmartListenerService.invoke(ClientSmartListenerService.java:139)
at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.listener.ClientSmartListenerService.register(ClientSmartListenerService.java:95)
... 9 more
```

Please help! How to solve it?

Comment: Please format your error message so that it's readable. Also no one has any idea what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

is Member [192.168.1.105]:5702 up and running?

Comment: yes its running and client is connected to this member, but when try to add item listener for queue from client that error is occures